# Why does chrome emit 'deviceorientation' on window focus?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, orientation

I have an app which would animate the box-shadow when the user rotates its device to simulate shadows. The web app is also accessible on desktop. I was expecting the 'deviceorientation' event to fire when the device's orientation.. changes. However, it seems that at even on desktop at every window focus the event fires. With mostly null values too. Code is as follows:

```
 function handleDeviceOrientation() {
       window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", event => {
            alert('Orientation event fired! Beta rotation: ' + event.beta);
            console.dir(event);
        }, true);
    }

handleDeviceOrientation();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnao44a9/) (switch between tabs to see the effect)

Any reason for this to happen?